# Explicit explanation as to what a return type is, why void is necessary

Tags: c#, methods, return

I'm sorry to ask a question that is conceptual but I am having a very hard time visualizing the idea of 'returning a value' from a method. I am still a beginner, sorry about this.

Take this code snippet for example:

```
public static NameGenerator(string x)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    string[] randomNamePossibilities = new string[15]
    {
        "John", "Billy", "Tommy", "Kyle", "Jackson", "George", "Paco",
        "Sruy", "Mateus", "Matt", 
        "Jared", "Sage", "Kai", "Trent", "Dillon"
    };   
    int randomNumberPicker = r.Next(15);
    return randomNamePossibilities[randomNumberPicker];        
}
```

notice how it returns the one-dimensional string array, randomNamePossibilities[15].  The intention is for this method to generate a randomized number with `Random r` (that has a maximum value of 15), and then for the method to return one of these randomized names from the array as a string.

The error I'm getting is with `NameGenerator()` & `return randomNamePossibilities[randomnumberPicker];` Giving me the errors 'Method must have a return type', and 'Since Person.NameGenerator(string) returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression.'

So my question is this: In explicitly simple terms, what does return do inside of a method like this? In what case is it used properly? Why is it that this code snippet gives me an error if I use void? How can I rewrite this to function well?

Comment: Are you sure that code even compiles...?

Comment: @maccettura It doesn't. That's the point of this question.

Comment: It does not. Sorry, I explained this in the second paragraph under the snippet

Comment: Consider this code: `int randomNumberPicker = r.Next(15);` `r.Next(15)` *returns* an integer value. Think of the integer value being emitted (sorry) from the back end of `r.Next()`, travelling through a tube represented by `=` (sorry!) and landing in `randomNumberPicker`.

Comment: You tell the compiler what a method will return by putting a type in front of the method name: `public static int Foo(int x) { return 9 * x; }`. Your `NameGenerator` method has no declared return type. I think you want it to be `public static string NameGenerator(string x) ...`

Comment: Pretty sure this `return randomNamePossibilities[)];` is a typo.  I assume you meant `return randomNamePossibilities[r];`.  If that's in your actual code, then that's the problem.

Comment: I guess I am just confused then.  If you call a method, and you want something back from it, **it needs to return something**.  The compiler needs to know what type its returning to make sure your code is valid.  That is why we give it a return type.  If you have a method that does **not need to return anything**, then the return type is `void`. If you mark a method as `void`, you can still use `return` to **exit** the method.  Although no value is being returned, you're still telling it when to return to the calling method.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Hi, yes, that was a typo. In the code it looks like this: `return randomNamePossibilities[randomNumberPicker];`

Comment: @EdPlunkett This makes perfect sense!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A return type is just that: it indicates what type you want to return from the method.

The method `string Hello() { return "Hello"; }` has the return type of `string`, and returns a string.

Your method declaration:

```
public static NameGenerator(string x)
```

Lacks a return type. The compiler forgives you for that insofar that it won't immediately stop evaluating the code in that method, but a return type is required for class methods in C#.

Note that the compiler first noticed your lack of a declared return type (*"Method must have a return type"*), and then assumes you want a `void` method. You cannot `return something;` from a `void` method (*"Since Person.NameGenerator(string) returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression"*).

If you *don't* want to return anything from a method, you declare its return type as `void`:

```
public void SayHello()
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Hello"); 
}
```

You can use the `return` keyword to (prematurely) exit a method, and for a non-void method, you'll have to return something at that point.

To fix your method, you need to add a return type:

```
public static string NameGenerator(string x)
{
    // ...
    int randomNumberPicker = r.Next(15);
    return randomNamePossibilities[randomNumberPicker];        
}
```

Now if you'd have a method that doesn't return anything, but you still want to return from it, you just use the return keyword:

```
public void HotDog()
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 12)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Morning");
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Not morning");
}
```

Here, `return` makes execution leave the method at that point.

Comment: Everything you are saying so far makes sense, and I experimented with it in my code and it made sense. I want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly: `public static string NameGenerator()` imagine I format it like this and then summon an instance of it like so: `name = NameGenerator();` is it EXACTLY the same as me doing `public static string NameGenerator(string x)` and then summoning it with `NameGenerator(name);` instead? Will both return one of the randomized names in the exact same way?

Comment: No, that's not the same. The first, parameterless method accepts no arguments, while the second does. Generally, parameters go in, return types come out of a method.

Comment: So in the first case I am simply calling upon the method to give me information, whereas in the second case I am bringing external information into the method and THEN making it give me information? Under that assumption, even in my case, the second example would not end up returning any information because of the incorrect formatting of `NameGenerator(name);` It would not have any place to store that information. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but for the second call to succeed (`NameGenerator(name)`), you'll have to have a method with one parameter.

Comment: So `NameGenerator(name)` would work with `public static string NameGenerator(string x)`

Comment: Yeah that's it.

Answer (score 0):

The return value indicates what a method returns as a value to the caller.

This can be a value, a reference, an adress (with unsafe code) or nothing at all.

Think of this simple function:

```
f(x) = m*x+n
```

when you use it in another context you go:

```
g(x) = f(x)*2+10^x
```

In this case, `f(x)` returns the value of itself into the other function.

This is the same way that programming languages treat methods (and thats why they are often called functions aswell).

But in the case you do not want to return anything, you use `void` to indicate that no return value is given.

This doesn't mean that the `return` keyword is without use.

`return` always exits the method when it is called no matter where within a method.

See this example:

```
public int Foo()
{
    int x = 0;
    return 2; //Exits the method
    return 0; //Will never be hit at all
}
```

You can use `return` in void methods without any value behind it to exit your method at any given location.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the code in your example, a return type is explicitly defined in the methods declaration. Example:

```
public int MethodName()
{
    int i = 1;
    return i;
}
```

Why is the return value important?

When you call your method (and sometimes you don't) the return value can be assigned or compared. Example:

```
if(MethodName() == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The returned value from MethodName is 1");
}
```

Another example:

```
int i2 = MethodName(); //i2 is now equal to 1, since MethodName returns a value of 1
```

More examples with a different return value:

```
public string StringMethod()
{
    string s = "this is a string";
    return s;
}

public void MainMethod()
{
    string newString = StringMethod(); //newString is now equal to "this is a string" 
    if(StringMethod().Equals(newString))
    {
        //this code block will run, since both string are "this is a string"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is missing the return type (the first 'string' word in this fixed code sample).

return instructs the runtime to calculate the value after the keyword 'return' and then stop executing the method and *return* to the method that called this method. It's redundant when it is the last line of a method, which is why some languages don't need it at all, but it is necessary for CSharp.

```
public static string NameGenerator(string x)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    string[] randomNamePossibilities = new string[15]
    {
        "John", "Billy", "Tommy", "Kyle", "Jackson", "George", "Paco",
        "Sruy", "Mateus", "Matt",
        "Jared", "Sage", "Kai", "Trent", "Dillon"
    };
    int randomNumberPicker = r.Next(15);
    return randomNamePossibilities[randomNumberPicker];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue of your snippet is, that your method signatur does not define a Return type. Either use `void` then you have a method and nothing is returned from this method (and no `return` keyword is allowed in the body. Or you define a return type such as `String`, `int` etc and you'll have a function returning some value/object. (`return` keyword required in the body).

Your method signature should look like

```
public static string GenerateRandonName()
```

Comment: Even methods with `void` return type can have `return` in the body. However it would be just `return;`. This will allow the control to go back to the calling method.